# Problema no autoplay do video

Tags: jquery

Adicionei um video logo quando inicia o site e eu queria que estivesse no autoplay.

Eu sei que se eu colocasse na página em html5 ele rodaria de boa como eu ja fiz o teste. Mas como está dentro desse box e usando o js, o mesmo não inicia.

O código do script em js que estou utilizando é esse:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
   $.colorbox({href:"comunicado.php"});
   $('#video_player').prop('autoplay', true);
});
</script>
```

e no video em html eu setei assim:

```html
<video width="99%" height="500" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source id="video_player" src="comercial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Tentei de varias formas, mas como nao sou expert nao sei o que está acontecendo. Gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês!

Comment: lembre-se que o navegador possuí restrições para vídeos configurados com "auto play", por exemplo são configurados como mudo por padrão

Answer (score 1):

As vezes são coisas simples que parece complexas. o seu codigo está correto so falta vc colocar (muted) e (loop)

ex.:

```html
<video autoplay="true" muted loop> 
    <source src="assets/4k-background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="assets/4k-background.ogg">
    <source src="assets/4k-background.webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Então eu ja tive um problema parecido com a tag video

tenta adiciona um muted dentro da tag

exemplo:

```
<video id="Home-vid" width="100%" autoplay="" muted="" loop="">
    <source src="files/video_home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

muted autoplay é sempre permitido

Aqui tem mais algumas informações:
[Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Salve Salve pessoal, depois de ler muito encontrei a solução em 29/01/2020.

```
<embed src="audio/fazer-pedido.mp3" type="audio/mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true">
<audio id="player" autoplay><source src="" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

O src="" do elemento audio deixe vazio, funciona no Android 8.0 com Chrome 72.0... Nada mais além disso.

Answer (score -1):

No HTML é apenas `autoplay`.

```
<video width="99%" height="500" id="video" controls autoplay>
    <source id="video_player" src="comercial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

E não precisa disso:

```
$('#video_player').prop('autoplay', true);
```

Faça assim no seu código JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('video').play();
```

E na tag `video` coloque `id="video"`.

Comment: Olá gumball acabei de fazer a alteração somente com o autoplay e o mesmo ainda não deu certo

Comment: Só se tem algum plugin interferindo nisso. Mas vou editar meu post com algo que você pode fazer.

Comment: Então fiz como você pediu: adicionei o código assim.. <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    $.colorbox({href:"comunicado.php"});
    document.getElementById('video').play();
   });
</script>

Comment: porém ainda nao deu, o site para referencia é o sculpconstrutora.com.br

Comment: Esse vídeo está dentro da página **comunicado.php** ?

Comment: Sim está. e fazendo um include na index

Comment: Então, dentro da **página comunicado.php** você faz `<script>document.getElementById('video').play();</script>`.

Comment: Fiz conforme me pediu e ainda nao deu o autoplay no video, nao consigo entender o por que disso :(

Answer (score -1):

```js
  $('document').ready(function(){
   var video = document.getElementById("meu_video"); 
   video.play();
  });
```

```html
    <video width="400" controls id='meu_video'>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>
```

Veja se funciona. Fiz os testes aqui e deu certo.

Comment: Bilico, seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Uma dica:  quando for responder tente explicar o porque você alterou o código de forma que explique o problema e a pessoa que perguntou entenda o porque da alteração. =)